# Double Sum Notation using Resursive functions Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion, math

I am kind of new to python, I am trying to get to this:

[image]

So far, I was able to use single sum and prod notations:

```
def m(n):
    if (n == 0): return 0
    return (2*n)+m(n-1)
print(m(6))
```

as:

[image]

I am not really sure how to implement a summation inside a summation.

Any hint will be appreciated (not trying to get spoonfed), but I think I can implement a third notation seeing a sum inside a sum notation.

Comment: You could use another recursive function, but an iterative approach would be much better in my opinion. Are you restricted to a recursive approach?

Comment: You also need to know the difference between sum notation and product notation. But both are basically just for loops.

Comment: Write a separate function for each product or sum. Since the 2nd and 3rd start from something other than `0`, you'll need to pass the starting index as a parameter, and compare with that for the base case.

Comment: Yes, I am restricted to using recursive functions only, I tried just adding a new function (j*i)

```
def s2(j, n):
 if (n == j): return 0
 return (j*n)+s2(n, n-1)
```

But not sure what values j and n should be on a recursive function

The difference between sum and product should be just the plus and muliplication symbols, and returning 1, to multiply by 1 the last time the function runs, and return 0 for summation, if Im not mistaken

Answer (score 0):

You can define a recursive function for each sum/product:

```py
n = 3

def prod_k(k, j, i):
    return (i + 6*j*k) * (1 if k == j else prod_k(k-1, j, i))

def sum_j(j, i):
    return prod_k(n, j, i) + (0 if j == i else sum_j(j-1, i))

def prod_i(i=n):
    return sum_j(n, i) * (1 if i == 0 else prod_i(i-1))

output = prod_i()
print(output) # 356912678808
```

But using generator expression might be easier to write:

```py
from math import prod

n = 3

output = prod(sum(prod(i + 6*j*k for k in range(j, n+1)) for j in range(i, n+1)) for i in range(0, n+1))
print(output) # 356912678808
```